# Serialize LambdaExpression to and from string for saving in a database

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, expression

Is it possible to serialize an `Expression<T>` or `LambdaExpression`? I need to save the expression tree in a database (`varchar` column).

```
var expr = (LambdaExpression)expression;
if (expr != null)
{   
    var newBody = Expression.Convert(expr.Body, typeof(string));
    var expr2 = Expression.Lambda(newBody, expr.Parameters);
    var castedExpression = expr2 as Expression<Func<ShipmentViewModel, string>>;

    Func = castedExpression.Compile();
}
```

I want to reconstruct the `LambdaExpression`, compile and reuse it. Currently, I'm not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions are not serialisable. However, there are some third-part tools that may help.

I would recommend looking at [Serialize.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serialize.Linq/). It is up to date, maintained, has a healthy number of downloads and will support .NET Framework 4.x as well as .NET Standard.

From the examples, it's pretty simple to use too:

```
Expression expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x");

// Serialize expression
var serializer = new ExpressionSerializer(new JsonSerializer());
string value = serializer.SerializeText(expression);
Console.WriteLine("value:" + value);

// Deserialize expression
var actualExpression = serializer.DeserializeText(value);
Console.WriteLine("actualExpression:" + actualExpression.ToJson());
```

Comment: They may not be serializable in the technical sense, but their `ToString` methods are epic.  `LambdaExpression.Lambda(Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(5), Expression.Constant(2))).ToString()` comes out to "() => 5 + 2".  I've written arbitrarily complex expressions and the `ToString` method held up. 
 Deserialization is what they're missing.  I'm frankly surprised that they didn't write a parse method that just did what ToString does in reverse.

Comment: @bvoyelr The `ToString` override is useful for debugging but doesn't contain anywhere near enough information for serialising.